# Use Custom URL Routing using Conventional ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to add constraints to routing.I am using conventional routing. Following is my code

Startup.cs

```
using Lab4MVC.Routing;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
//builder.Services.AddMvc(x => x.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

//app.UseMvc(); 
//app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
//app.UseMvc(routes => {
//    Routing.LoadRoutes(routes);
//});

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    Routing.LoadRoutes(endpoints)
    
);

app.Run();
```

Routing.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

namespace Lab4MVC.Routing
{
    public static class Routing
    {
        public static void LoadRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
        {

            routeBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name:"Route1",pattern: "/Customer/Add/{Id}",defaults: new
            {
                contoller = "Customer",
                action = "Add"
            });

            //routeBuilder.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Customer}/{action=Add}");
            //routeBuilder.MapFallbackToController("Add", "Customer");
        }
    }
}
```

CustomerController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Lab4MVC.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        
        public IActionResult Add(int Id)
        {
            return View("CustomerScreen");
        }


        public IActionResult Update()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Delete()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I am learning ASP.NET Core. Struggling to call Route with the pattern. I am able to call Controller using the default route.

When adding constraint it is not called. Also, please guide me on how to use the following pattern lets say Customer/New/1. Here I want to change my action name. Don't want to use Add URL.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean when you call `Customer/Add/1` the URL wants to show `Customer/New/1`?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the correct meaning you want to express should be that you don't want others to know what method you call in the background. Suppose you have a get request, and the original route is `/Customer/Add? param=test,` you want to display the path as `/Person/Add` through a custom method, similar to this requirement, right?

If it is like this，you can use `Rewrite` method.And you can refer to this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

It is worth noting that：`app.UseRewriter()` must be used before `app.UseStaticFiles()`.

Comment: Yes,I don't want to use the same controller name and action method name in my code. I want to hide that and use Customer/New as URL. Since I can do this easily in old MVC but in MVC Core I don't know how to do this. I tried app.UseRewriter() but it is not working. I don't want to redirect user to different URL. I want to handle using Routing.

Comment: Can you accept [IIS url writing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)?